# react-native picker styling custom font

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using the Picker component which I have successfully customised within my styles.xml file in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerItem">
<item name="android:fontFamily">Lato-Bold</item>
<item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
</style>
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
<item name="android:fontFamily">Lato-Bold</item>
<item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
<item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

At the moment my custom fontFamily: Lato-Bold is being ignored. Does anyone know how to get a custom Spinner font to work?

Comment: Also interested in this, I've tried to add the font using these instructions:  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html, but haven't had any luck.  This doesn't work for me if I add a new font 'quicksand' in the res/font directory.

    <style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/quicksand</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a custom font family by following the official steps [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html).

However, some things were not that clear when I was following that guide, so here comes a summary of the steps you need to take (please don't skip reading the official guide, as this is only a complement to it):

1. Create a new font resource directory (`res/font`)
2. Add your font files there. Your filenames should not include any character outside of `a-z0-9_` (must be lowercase). Example: `res/font/lato_bold.ttf`.
3. Create a font family file. In our example, it would be `res/font/lato.xml` and have the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="700"
        android:font="@font/lato_bold" />
</font-family>
```

4. Reference your font in your custom styles as follows:

```xml
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato_bold</item>
```